# What is an example of the email protocol syntax to include a Text and HTML version within an email?

Tags: html-email

If I want to include, in an email, both an HTML version and a plain text version (for non html email readers), what is the protocol to include in it to specify each?

Comment: I sympathize with the down vote as there is no research shown, but on the other hand it's a valid question with a simple answer. What's glaringly obvious to some is not to everybody.

Answer (score 1):

MIME - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME

It's an internet standard and it would be a rare language that doesn't have a library for creating and handling MIME email messages.

Comment: Thanks, I'm deleting the question. Hope that doesn't hurt your rep. Thanks!

Comment: I could care less about my rep.

Comment: Argg... I can't delete it b/c it's been flagged for a moderator. #RedTapeHell ;-(